# Question On Text Parsing In Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, text-parsing

I want to parse the line as this,

```
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,reply
```

And I want the output as below,

```
1
2
title including several white spaces
abbr
single
Here22There  # identify <-> and translate it to 22; 
reply
```

I am wondering how to parse the line above?

Method 1.
I plan to split the whole line to four segments then parse the individual sub segments.

segment1. `S1,F2`

segment2. `title including several white spaces`

segment3. `abbr`

segment4. `single,Here<->There,reply`

Method 2.
I just write a complex regular expression statement to parse it.

Which method is more make sense for my practice?

Appreciated on any comments or suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help with Perl reg ex? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192213/need-help-with-perl-reg-ex) That one comes after this one, but is a better question with some better answers--it's the same exact basic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input be in the format specified you could use a regex like:

```
^S(\d+),F(\d+)\s+(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s+(.*?),(.*?),(.*)$
```

[**Codepad link**](http://codepad.org/2FAtURm9)

Comment: Hi. Why your expression end with `$` (1 dollar)? I tested and found it works well end with/without `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your *first method*, what you can do is like first **split the string by comma**,like

```
my $line =
 'S1,F4  title including several white spaces (abbr) single,Here<->There,reply';
 my ($field1, $field2, $field3, $field4) = split /,/, $line;
```

and then **apply regex on the field** containg substring `S1` and `F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single` like

```
my ($field5) = $field1 =~ /S(\d+)/;
my ($field6, $field7, $field8, $field9) = 
                    $field2 =~ m/^F(\d+)\s+(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s+(.*?)$/;
```

It will work for all these strings, and help to avoid using and making complex regular expressions,

```
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,reply
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,[reply]
```