# Need help with Perl reg ex?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

Here is my text file forms.

```
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,reply
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,[reply]
```

How to change my reg ex to work on all the three forms above?

```
/^S(\d),F(\d)\s+(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s+(.*?),(.*?)[,](.*?)$/
```

I tried replace `(.*?)$/` with `[.*?]$/`. It doesn't work. I guess I shouldn't use `[]`(square brackets) to match the possible word of `[reply]`(including the `[]`).

Actually, my general question should be how to match the possible characters better in Reg exp using Perl? I looked up the online *PerlDoc* webpages. But it is hard for me to find out the useful information based on my Perl knowledge level. That's why I also asked some stupid questions.

Appreciated for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using negated character classes:

```
 /^S(\d),F(\d)\s+([^()]*?)\s+\(([^()]+)\)\s+([^,]*),([^,]*)(?:,(.*?))?$/
```

When incorporated into this script:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my($s,$f,$title,$abbr,$single,$here,$reply) =
        $_ =~ m/^S(\d),F(\d)\s+([^()]*?)\s+\(([^()]+)\)\s+([^,]*),([^,]*)(?:,(.*?))?$/;
    $reply ||= "<no reply>";
    print "S$s F$f <$title> ($abbr) $single : $here : $reply\n";
}
```

And run on the original data file, it produces:

```
S1 F2 <title including several white spaces> (abbr) single : Here<->There : reply
S1 F2 <title including several white spaces> (abbr) single : Here<->There : <no reply>
S1 F2 <title including several white spaces> (abbr) single : Here<->There : [reply]
```

You should probably also use the 'xms' suffix to the expression to allow you to document it more easily:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;

    my($s,$f,$title,$abbr,$single,$here,$reply) =
        $_ =~ m/^
                S(\d) ,             # S1
                F(\d) \s+           # F2
                ([^()]*?) \s+       # Title
                \(([^()]+)\) \s+    # (abbreviation)
                ([^,]*) ,           # Single
                ([^,]*)             # Here or There
                (?: , (.*?) )?      # Optional reply
                $
               /xms;

    $reply ||= "<no reply>";
    print "S$s F$f <$title> ($abbr) $single : $here : $reply\n";
}
```

I confess I'm still apt to write one-line monsters - I'm trying to mend my ways.

Answer (score 1):

You know that brackets in regular expression are reserved for declaring sets of characters that you want to match? So, for a real bracket, you need to escape it, or to enclose it in brackets (`[[]` or `[]]`), isn't that obfuscated?!.

Try `(\[.*?\]|.*?)` to indicate that optional brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/^S(\d),F(\d)\s+(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s+(.*?),(.*?)(,(\[reply\]|reply))?$/
```

This will match the optional (`?`) part `,(\[reply\]|reply)` which is either `,[reply]` or `,reply`, i.e.,

- (nothing)
- `,reply`
- `[,reply]`

BTW, your `[,]` means "one character of the following: `,`". Exactly the same as a literal `,` within the regex. *If* you wanted to make your `[,](.*?)$` work, you should use `(,(.+))?$` to match either nothing *or* a comma followed by any (non-empty) string.

---

**EDIT**

If the following are also valid:

```
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,[reply
S1,F2  title including several white spaces  (abbr) single,Here<->There,reply]
```

Then you could use `(,\[?reply\]?)?` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the last part optional by using the `(?:..)?` as:

```
^S(\d),F(\d)\s+(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s+(.*?),(.*?)(?:,(.*))?$
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/OvfjYi9F)